# Language Allowing Rapid Development And Refactoring To Best Practices

Tags: php, refactoring, strong-typing

I have looked at languages such as PHP, Python, Ruby and Skala. However, I haven't found any language that meets the requirement below:

I'm looking for a language that is lax enough to quickly write a web application prototype with (without bothering with best practices), but is also sophisticated enough to support me when trying to "refactor to design patterns".

Is there a language/web framework specifically created for this purpose? An example would be PHP, optionally acting like Java if the developer requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring bad code "to design patterns" has nothing to do with the language's sophistication.

You can really try any of the mentioned languages and see which one is the easiest for you to learn, you can't go wrong with any of them.

Comment: Well. My problem with PHP, for example, is that it doesn't allow strong-typing as much as a language like Skala does. However, my problem with Skala is that at the level of creating something like a prototype I don't need to spend 15 minutes on defining a type because at that stage, it's all about rapid development.